# Intuition behind the proof of Tietze Extension Theorem (or a weaker version thereof)

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, compactness

I am going through the proof of a weaker version of the Tietze extension theorem:

If $f : K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is a continuous function, where $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, then it can be extended to a continuous function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, i.e, $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in K$.

I am looking at the proof which is essentially as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081372/continuous-extension-on-compact-set-in-mathbbrn). I understand the proof by just going through the motions, but what is the intuition behind it? What motivates us to define $\varphi_i$ and $f$ on $K^c$ as it is done here?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the basic idea is to define $g(x)$ to be a weighted average of $f(y)$ for points $y$ that are nearby to $x$ and in $K$.  That's exactly what the formula for $g$ on $K^c$ does: it takes an average of the values $f(a_i)$, weighted by $2^{-i}\varphi_i(x)$.  The trick is then to figure out how to choose the weighting functions $\varphi_i$ so that the resulting function is continuous on the boundary of $K$.  The idea is that as you approach a point $a\in K$, the weight of the $\varphi_i$ corresponding to points near $a$ should dominate all the other weights, so the weighted average you compute just approaches $f(a)$.

So what does the function $\varphi_i$ do?  It asks, "how close is $a_i$ to being the closest point to $x$ in $K$?".  If $a_i$ actually is the closest point, then $|x-a_i|=\rho(x,K)$ and so $\varphi_i(x)=1$.  If $a_i$ is not the closest point, then $\varphi_i$ decreases with how far proportionately it is from being the closest point, reaching $0$ once it is twice as far away as the closest point.  This way, the weighted sum we will use to define $g(x)$ depends only on the values of $f$ at nearby points of $K$ (with the threshold for "nearby" getting stricter and stricter as $x$ approaches $K$).

Another important technical point is the fact that we are using a countable dense subset.  Naively, you might like to take a weighted average simply over *all* points of $K$, weighted according to how close they are.  Of course this runs into technical issues of how to define such an average--you would need some sort of nice measure on $K$.  The trick of using the countable dense subset is to let you be able to just add up all the weights instead of needing to come up with a measure, as long as you multiply them by $2^{-i}$ to make sure the sum converges.

Comment: I was thinking of a weighted average as well, but the $2^{-i}$ in the denominator depends on the arbitrary indexing of the dense subset, and not the distance as you said. So you could have a point $a_i$ far closer to $x$ and a point $a_j$ far further, but if $i >>j$ then the weight 2$^{-i}$ is far more 'dampening'. Does the fact that it's dense simply assure us that this indexing issue won't arise because there will always be some other $a_i$ close that isn't victim to unfortunate indexing?

Comment: It doesn't matter because, as I remarked, the threshold for "nearby" gets stricter and stricter as $x$ approaches $K$.  When $x$ is within $\epsilon$ of $K$, then the weights of _all_ points more than $2\epsilon$ away from $x$ will be $0$, so we're just taking some weighted average of points within a $2\epsilon$-ball.  It doesn't matter what the weights are within that ball, since as $x$ approaches some point $a\in K$, all points within that ball are close to $a$ and so since $f$ is continuous the values you're averaging are all close to $f(a)$.

Comment: So in fact, while the idea is to make nearby points have weights that dominate faraway points, the actual implementation here ends up making them dominate in a very strong sense, with the weights of faraway points just being $0$.  This is of course related to the issue you raise with the $2^{-i}$: if you didn't make the faraway weights just zero out, you would have to be very careful about the effects of those $2^{-i}$ factors needed to make the sum converge.